# How to traverse a structure response: dialogflow

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

The following response is received from Dialogflow's `detect_intent` API call. How do I traverse the response structure and extract the `string_value` entries?

I'm using python. Looking for a solution that will work for various data structures. Return null/error if `string_value` not found.

Response request:

`response = session_client.detect_intent(session=session, query_input=query_input)`

Response example:

```
fields {
  key: "google"
  value {
    struct_value {
      fields {
        key: "expectUserResponse"
        value {
          bool_value: false
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "richResponse"
        value {
          struct_value {
            fields {
              key: "items"
              value {
                list_value {
                  values {
                    struct_value {
                      fields {
                        key: "simpleResponse"
                        value {
                          struct_value {
                            fields {
                              key: "textToSpeech"
                              value {
                                string_value: "<speak>Welcome to Your App. To get started, login with your ID on your Google Home app.</speak>"
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "userStorage"
        value {
          string_value: "{\"data\":{\"id\":\"YzA3MmNiNWEtMWI1Ny00NTMzLTlhN2EtYmJlZmQ1NDQ0MzMw\"}}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please copy and paste your response exactly? This seems to be ill formed (it's missing colons and quotes for example). See if you can paste just the raw text of the JSON response.

Comment: @duhaime This is not a JSON response. It's a custom data structure that can be traversed manually via dot-notation (example: `response.fields.value.fields`, etc.) But such a solution is both laborious and is not dynamic. Is it possible to traverse said structure via a loop, etc?

Comment: Ahh, it must be a class with attributes. How did you create that tree structure displayed above?

Comment: @duhaime It's Dialogflow API's response. Response section: https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment
The response from the service should have the following fields:

Comment: Excellent. Can you please post a minimal code snippet that generates `response`? That will help others help you.

Answer (score 0):

Response can be parsed using Google's protocol buffers:

Example:

`response.query_result.webhook_payload.get_or_create_struct('google').get_or_create_struct('richResponse').get_or_create_list('items')[0].get_or_create_struct('simpleResponse').fields['textToSpeech'].string_value`